# how can I insert a plot in Maple to a latex document?

Tags: graphics

I want to insert a plot done by Maple to a LaTeX document. Please specify its commands.

Comment: Export from Maple to PDF and `\includegraphics{filename}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually, we prefer a working document, not just `please specify its commands`. In addition to http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t 's comment: `\usepackage{graphicx}` is needed

Comment: I used  Torbjorn T. command but there was a LaTex error:cannot determine size of graphic in(file name). (no Bounding Box)

Comment: What file format did you export to, and how did you compile the `.tex` file? That error has been asked about before ( see http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=cannot%20determine%20size%20of%20graphic) so you could look at some of those.